# Layouts and resources not being resolved

Tags: android, layout

I'm completely confused as to why my layouts aren't being resolved.  They're there, spelled correctly, and R.java is present and not throwing an obvious error.

```
    import android.R;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;


    public class myApp extends Activity {
ImageButton b;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.oraclebutton);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(myApp.this, TestIntro.class);
            myApp.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        } 
    });
}
}
```

Comment: If you are using eclipse try going to Project->Clean and clean your project so it can rebuild and force a regeneration of the `R` class. The code example is a little meaningless without seeing the resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the reference you have to android.R (just delete the line "import android.R;")

It's likely trying to search in there for your resource files.

Comment: ugh, yep. that's it! thanks so much! it won't let me accept the answer for 5 minutes, but i'll leave this up and accept later